# How to use ODE as a objective function in MATLAB for optimization

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I have an ODE equation:

```
d[ras]/dt = x1*[0.4]*[0.7] + (x2 + x3)*[0.013].
```

Now I need to optimize this equation. So how should I represent this equation in a `.m` file so as to use it as objective function for optimization in MATLAB?

DO i need to first solve the ODE or can just use it as objective function?

Comment: Could you describe the problem in more details? e.g. what is `x1`, what do you want to optimize.

Comment: Another user asked a similar question, which i answered, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636834/ode45-solving-of-diff-equation-with-further-fitting-to-exp-results/26640136#26640136 Although the answer was neither upvoted, nor accepted, I strongly believe that it solved the problem, which was finding optimal parameters for fitting the result of a numerical integration with ``ode45()``, which seems to be analogue to your "question".