# how to estimate and optimize the parameters of coupled nonlinear ODE's

Tags: matlab, optimization, ode

I have a set of coupled nonlinear ODE's, i need to solve these ODE's, then estimate and optimize the parameters using genetic algorithm or any function so as to minimize the difference between experimental and simulated data.

i have all the initial values for all state variables and the range(1-10) for the parameters to be estimated. I am new to MATLAB please forgive if i had made any syntax errors.
following is the code:

```
function dx = reaction( t,x,k )

dx = zeros(6,1);

dx(1)=0;

dx(2)= k(1)*x(1) - k(2)*x(2) - k(3)*x(5) + k(4)*x(6);

dx(3)=0;

dx(4) = -k(2)*x(3)*x(4) + k(3)*x(5);

dx(5) = k(8)*x(3)*x(4) - k(7)*x(5) - k(3)*x(2)*x(5) + k(5)*x(6);

dx(6) = k(6)*x(2)*x(5) - k(3)*x(6) - k(4)*x(2)*x(6);

end


function objective

k01=1:10;
k02=1:10;
k03=1:10;
k04=1:10;
k05=1:10;
k06=1:10;
k07=1:10;
k08=1:10; %//range of parameters to lie in

exp=[8;0;0.8;12;0;0];      %//experimental data

time=[0;5;10;15;20;25];  %//time span

x01=8;
x02=0;
x03=0.8;
x04=12;
x05=0;
x06=0; %// initial values of state variables

tspan = [min(time),max(time)];

 k_opt = fminsearch(@minimize, [k1,k2,k3,k4,k5,k6,k7,k8])
function e = minimize(k1,k2,k3,k4,k5,k6,k7,k8)
            sol = ode45(@reaction, tspan, [x01,x02,x03,x04,x05,x06],[], [k1,k2,k3,k4,k5,k6,k7,k8]);
            y_hat = deval(sol, time); % // evaluate solution at given times
            e = sum((y_hat' - exp).^2); % // compute squarederror           
end

% // plot with optimal parameter
[T,X] = ode45(@reaction, tspan, [x01,x02,x03,x04,x05,x06], [], k_opt);
figure
plot(time, exp,'ko', 'markersize',10,'markerfacecolor','black')
hold on
plot(T,Y, 'r--', 'linewidth', 2)

end
```

Comment: Did you prepare the code to solve the system for a fixed set of parameters? If so, please add the code, so it is easier to start helping. Here is a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636834/ It should not matter if solving a system of equations or a single equation. The syntax keeps the same

Comment: i didnt prepared the code yet, actually I need to use ga optimization toolbox for the optimization purpose. So how can i simultaneously solve the ODE's and pass it the same in the Fitness function of ga toolbox. i am having a problem to link ODE solver with the optimization toolbox. @Nras

Comment: Well maybe start with my "suggestion" do add the code to solve the system for a fixed parameter set.

Comment: I had added a code, please help to correct and modify the above code. I tried to develop this code with help of your earlier modified code on the similar problem. Thank you @Nras

Comment: Are the experimental data (stored in ``exp``, which is a function and should not be abused as variable name) the values for all state variables in the last timestep? Or is it the values for one state variable for the given times in ``time`` (like the plot command suggests?)

Comment: experimental data stored in 'exp' can be replaced by any variable name say 'data'. the values for all state variables are initial values at time 0. @Nras

Comment: you are not making things easy for me. Please answer all questions (last try). What does the data in exp refer to? Is it the desired result for all state variables  at the last time step? OR is it the values for one of the six state variables at all six given timestamps in ``time``? I have code prepared for days now, but i will not post it as an answer untill that is clear.

Comment: yes data in exp refer's to the desired result for all state variables at last time step. @Nras

Answer (score 0):

See this as a start (still needs some work). It is the best that i can come up with.

Your plot `plot(time, exp,'ko', 'markersize',10,'markerfacecolor','black')` doesn't make sense to me as it plots the data over the time, which (referring to your latest comment) is not what `exp` should be. Thats why i was asking in the comments

The optimization stops with an error of about 139.3828 for me, also raising some warnings about problems with the numerical integration. The optimal parameterset is

```
k_opt =
```

-0.2258    6.2298   -1.2666    3.6352   -1.8671    0.0001    2.5592   -2.2011

Here comes the code:

```
function main

k0 = ones(1,8);

exp=[8;0;0.8;12;0;0];      %//experimental data

time=[0;5;10;15;20;25];  %//time span

%// initial values of state variables
x01=8;
x02=0;
x03=0.8;
x04=12;
x05=0;
x06=0; 
x0 = [x01,x02,x03,x04,x05,x06];

tspan = [min(time),max(time)];

k_opt = fminsearch(@minimize, k0)
function e = minimize(k0)
            [t,y_hat] = ode45(@reaction, tspan, x0,[], k0);
%             y_hat = deval(sol, time(end)); % // evaluate solution at given times
            e = sum((y_hat(end,:)' - exp).^2) % // compute squarederror '          
end

% // plot with optimal parameter
[T,Y] = ode45(@reaction, tspan, [x01,x02,x03,x04,x05,x06], [], k_opt);
figure
subplot(1,2,1)
plot(time(end), exp, '*', 'markersize',15)
hold on
plot(T,Y, 'linewidth', 2)

% // Scatter: data vs model
subplot(1,2,2)
scatter(Y(end,:), exp)
hold on
axis equal
grid on
xlabel('model')
ylabel('data')
disp('yay')
end

function dx = reaction(t, x, k)
dx = zeros(6,1);
dx(1)=0;
dx(2)= k(1)*x(1) - k(2)*x(2) - k(3)*x(5) + k(4)*x(6);
dx(3)=0;
dx(4) = -k(2)*x(3)*x(4) + k(3)*x(5);
dx(5) = k(8)*x(3)*x(4) - k(7)*x(5) - k(3)*x(2)*x(5) + k(5)*x(6);
dx(6) = k(6)*x(2)*x(5) - k(3)*x(6) - k(4)*x(2)*x(6);

end
```

And two plots of the result. Blue and red are fit quite well, however, they do not change while integrating. I do not know about the others i.e. if your equations are correct and actually can reproduce the result.[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but still i have few queries.(please ignore plot function, that's my mistake i didn't frame it properly)  1.how can i optimize parameters in a certain given range(upper bound and lower bound). 2.I need to use ga toolbox for optimization, so how can i relate the sol. of ODE45 with ga toolbox for optimization instead of fminsearch. 3.I tried the above code to optimize around 110 parameters, but it gave an error (error using horzcat, out of memory) is this a problem related to my computer or optimizing such large parameters is not possible ?@Nras

Comment: @swapnil90 Well I am not an expert in optimization, but fitting 110 parameters sounds alot like overfitting. I never used ga toolbox, but from the optimization toolbox, you can use ``fmincon`` for *conditioned* optimization. There you can set lower bounds and upper bounds for every parameter (each in a vector).

Comment: Can u suggest which input(function) should be given(with respect to above code) for fmincon toolbox. I tried using minimize function but failed. I am not getting how to make output of ODE45 as input for optimization toolbox(fmincon). @Nras

Comment: @swapnil90 You simply replace ``fminsearch`` by ``fmincon`` and pass vectors as arguments for ``lb`` and ``ub``. Like so: ``k_opt = fmincon(fun, k0, [], [], [], [], lb, ub)``. Where the i-th optimal parameter ``k(i)`` will be greater than ``lb(i)`` and lower than ``ub(i)``.